# Is this an "If and only if" proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My task is to show that some particular class of sets $F$ is the class of sets of the form $A$ (I'm leaving out the details of the question).

My question is as follows:

To complete this task, must I show that if a set is of form $A$ then it belongs to the class $F$, and that if a set belongs to the class $F$ then it has the form $A$?

The reason I ask is that the writer of the textbook has solutions in the back, and seems to have intended only the former (if a set is in the class $F$, it has the form $A$).

Comment: Yes, of course to show $A=F$ you have to show $A\subset F$ and $F\subset A$. Regarding that solution in the back of the book, maybe the author  regarded $A\subset F$ is obvious? (Can't say whether that seems reasonable without knowing what $A$ and $F$ are...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that two (classes of) sets are the same, you have to show that the first contains the second and vice versa. In short - yes.